# Styling text in localization files — bold, italic, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

What techniques/methods are there for dealing with emphasized or stylized text in localized strings?

For example, how might a brief title such as the one below (4–8 words) be italicized?

> Welcome to *the Machine*, John.

Is there a more efficient way than 3 lookups, plus a variable to define the structure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate) it says:

> Third, it'll mark the translation as safe HTML if the key has the suffix “_html” or the last element of the key is the word “html”. For example, calling translate(“footer_html”) or translate(“footer.html”) will return a safe HTML string that won't be escaped by other HTML helper methods. This naming convention helps to identify translations that include HTML tags so that you know what kind of output to expect when you call translate in a template.

So you need to append suffix `_html` to your key and now you can use html in your locales.

For example this is your locale file:

```
en:
  welcome:
    html: '<b>Hello!</b> This is first way to style your locales!'
  welcome_html: '<b>Hi again!</b> This is second way to style your locales!'
```

Now just set `I18n.t 'en.welcome.html'` or `I18n.t 'en.welcome_html'` in your views. That's all! :)